# Disallow typing after reaching input max length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few inputs on my page that need to have a max length of sorts and this is working to an extent except that an extra number keeps being added because of a plugin we're using...and no I can't get rid of the plugin causing it.

To fix this I need to remove one character from the input field. I have gotten to the point where it will remove it from the value of the input, but it is still showing on the screen...which is the issue.

Is there a way to disallow typing after they hit a certain point using JavaScript? I cannot use max length in the case because the virtual keyboard we are using ignores that completely.

I have something like this

```
var target = event.currentTarget;
var name = $(target).attr("name");
var validationLength = $(target).attr("validation").length;

$('input[name="'+name+'"]').on('keyup keydown change', function () {
    if($(this).val().length > validationLength){
        $(this).val().substr(0,$(this).val().length-1);
    };
});
```

And like I said this will remove it from the value of the input, but not what the user actually sees on the screen (the most important part). Any help would much appreciated!

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please update your question's tags with it.

Comment: @j08691 I just added it... Initially when I posted it would not let me.

Comment: Have you ever heard about the attribute called "maxlength"?

Comment: @epascarello If you read my question you will see I have stated I cannot use that because of a virtual keyboard.

Comment: To set the val you would need: `$(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,$(this).val().length-1));`

Comment: So how can a virtual keyboard override the maxlength of a input? That is where I am confused. Does the virtual keyboard actually trigger events on the text element?

Comment: `$(this).val().substr(0,$(this).val().length-1)` has no effect

Comment: @hindmost put that as an answer. :)

Comment: @epascarello It takes away all the focus from the input and actually will insert the text for you. It's really weird and I unfortunately can't change it I just have to find ways around it.

Comment: @hindmost Just removing it from the value, not the actual screen.

Comment: You are not setting the value with the trimmed string.

Comment: @epascarello ...Yeah, I think I've been staring at this too long! Oops! :)

Comment: From a usability perspective I prefer the system stackoverflow uses for comments. Where you can overshoot the amount then edit it down until you hit the max length.

Comment: @MartinSmith, initially that was what I was doing, but again this stupid keyboard was interfering and allowing all the overshoot to show in the input. I really dislike this keyboard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validationLength = 10;

$('#test').on('keyup keydown change', function () {
    if($(this).val().length > validationLength){

        val=$(this).val().substr(0,$(this).val().length-1);
        $(this).val(val);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mctkpLph/

Comment: That fiddle is not working... and it just removed all the text from my input all together in my app... EDIT: while the fiddle isn't working the part about my app was my bad!

Comment: hm... strange. works for me (if i understand what you want actually) :)

Comment: Yeah, works great in my app, but for some reason not when I try it in the fiddle. Very odd! Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: Also set and event on blur to check the content isn't more than 10 chars (in case a user pastes text in).